# Reledmac for Arabic edition (with arabluatex), minor problem with critical apparatus

Tags: arabic, reledmac

I'm really grateful for the help offered on this problem so far. Under arabluatex, the problem I posted two days ago (Reledmac for Arabic edition, problem with critical apparatus) is solved. It also solves a further problem I had with use of the \lemma command, exemplified in the third of the Arabic paragraphs below.

However, there are still 3 minor problems. (1) the apparatus isn't left-justified, (2) the numbers in the Arabic text are in reverse order (I couldn't see that before with "22"), (3) texing generates two error notice, both reading "Undefined control sequence. (\pend[\bigskip]...)" (which may not matter?).

I'd be really grateful for any (further!) help.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertineotf} 

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english} 

\usepackage[noend,nofamiliar,noeledsec,series={A}]{reledmac}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}
%\Xbeforeinserting{\setLR}
\Xlemmaseparator{]}

\newcommand{\ta}{\txarb}

\linenumincrement{5} \firstlinenum{5}

\title{The Epistle on Logic for Shams al-Dīn} \date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\beginnumbering

\pstart[\setRL]
%
\begin{arab}
٢٢- وأمّا الثالث فإن امتنع انفكاكه عن معروضه فهو
\edtext{\arb{اللازم}}{\Afootnote{RT : \ta{العرضي اللازم} S.}} وإلّا فهو
\edtext{\arb{العرض المفارق}}{\Afootnote{R : \ta{العرضي المفارق} ST.}}
%
\end{arab}
\pend[\bigskip]

\pstart
\begin{arab}
%
 والعرضيّ المفارق إمّا سريع الزوال كحَمَرة الخجْل وصُفْرة الوَجَل، وإمّا بطيئه
 كالشيْب والشباب.
%
\end{arab}
\pend[\bigskip]

\pstart
\begin{arab}
%
والأول هو النوع 
\edtext{\arb{الحقيقيّ}}{\Afootnote{\textLR{T} : - \textLR{RS}}}
سواء كان متعدّد الأشخاص، وهو المقول في جواب ما هو بحسب الشركة
والخصوصيّة معا كالإنسان، أو غير متعدّد الأشخاص، وهو المقول في جواب ما هو بحسب
\edtext{\arb{والخصوصيّة معا كالإنسان، أو غير متعدّد الأشخاص، وهو المقول في جواب ما هو بحسب}}{\lemma{\ta{والخصوصيّة... بحسب}}\Afootnote{ST, in mg. R}}
   الخصوصيّة المحضة كالشمس، فهو إذن كلّيّ مقول على واحد أو على كثيرين متّفقين بالحقائق 
   في جواب ما هو.
%
\end{arab}
\pend[\bigskip]
%
\pstart
\begin{arab}
%
١٨- وهو قريب إن كان الجواب عن الماهيّة وعن بعض ما يشاركها فيه هو الجواب عنها وعن كلّ ما يشاركها فيه كالحيوان بالنسبة إلى الإنسان، وبعيد إن كان الجواب عنها وعن بعض ما يشاركها فيه غير الجواب عنها وعن البعض الآخر. 
%
\end{arab}
\pend[\bigskip]
%
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: please open a github issue. I will look this week-end.

Comment: your undefined control sequence is on "\textLR". Not on "pend". Are you sur of the use of "\textLR" with lualatex?

Comment: I think you must set the the \setRL BEFORE the \pstart and not inside the optional argument of \pstart.

Comment: @Tony: Out of genuine interest: what work are you editing?

Comment: Hi Clint, it's Najm al-Din al-Katibi's Shamsiyya (most frequently taught logic text in history?), written in Maragha in the 1260s. What I've put in the question is just random paragraphs, one (as is obvious) badly mis-typed. The main manuscript I'm using is from 1280 by his student Hilli, transcribed 3 years after K's death.

Comment: Maïeul: thank you, you're absolutely right: I've got rid of \textLR throughout, and put \setRL before the \pstart. Now everything is resolved except the left-justification of the apparatus. I'm not sure I know how to open a github issue, but I'll look around the site and see if I can find out.

Comment: Actually, Maïeul, I think it's completely solved. I put in more text and everything (including the apparatus) looks great. Thank you (and thanks to Robert).

Comment: Actually `arabluatex` does not load `luabidi` at all.  Instead it provides its own commands, such as `\LR{<arg>}`, `\RL{<arg>}`, `\RLfootnote{<arg>}` `\LRfootnote{<arg>}`, `\setLR`, `\setRL`.  See the documentation, sect. 8 on pp. 28-31.